# Retrieve sqlite3* from sqlite3_stmt*

Tags: c++, sqlite

If I have a prepared statement - `sqlite3_stmt*`, is there a way I can retrieve from it the `sqlite3*` database for which it was prepared?

I.e. a function looking like this:

```
sqlite3* sqlite3_get_database_from_statement(sqlite3_stmt* statement);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, found the answer after searching in the headers a bit, this is the function I was looking for:

```
/*
** CAPI3REF: Find The Database Handle Of A Prepared Statement
**
** ^The sqlite3_db_handle interface returns the [database connection] handle
** to which a [prepared statement] belongs.  ^The [database connection]
** returned by sqlite3_db_handle is the same [database connection]
** that was the first argument
** to the [sqlite3_prepare_v2()] call (or its variants) that was used to
** create the statement in the first place.
*/
SQLITE_API sqlite3 *sqlite3_db_handle(sqlite3_stmt*);
```